# Monitoring table fields

Tags: firebird

I have started to check monitoring tables. Could someone explain what do these Fields means?

```
 MON$TRANSACTIONS (started transactions)
             - MON$TOP_TRANSACTION (top transaction)
             - MON$OLDEST_TRANSACTION (local OIT number)
             - MON$OLDEST_ACTIVE (local OAT number)
MON$TRANSACTIONS (started transactions)
         - MON$TRANSACTION_ID (transaction ID)
         - MON$ATTACHMENT_ID (attachment ID)
         - MON$STATE (transaction state)
             0: idle
             1: active
         - MON$TIMESTAMP (transaction start date/time)
         - MON$TOP_TRANSACTION (top transaction)
         - MON$OLDEST_TRANSACTION (local OIT number)
         - MON$OLDEST_ACTIVE (local OAT number)
```

Comment: Could you ask a more explicit question? The description is already in the parentheses and most of these terms (except maybe "top transaction") are standard Firebird terminology. For top transaction, see http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/rlsnotes217.html#rnfb210-mon . For an explanation of OIT and OAT see http://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/general/doc_67 The others are in my opinion self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your links

Comment: Were these the things you were specifically asking about? If so I will try to post a more detailed answer later this week.

Comment: Hi Mark, it is really nice of you, if you can give me more information about this theme, if you have a time. Actually I would like to trace database activity in the past time for example queries which run, number of fetchs, elapsed time ( generally statistic about the query). What I have found is `Audit/Trace Services`. I have some problem to use it, you have answered my question. Thanks a lot :-)